# Face still too bright despite merged vertices?

Tags: vertices, faces, normals

Despite I have merged the too close vertices and flipped the normal this face is still too bright for some reason. It uses the same material and I have managed to make the left door of the trailer model correctly but I have no idea what's wrong with the right side door...

[image]

[image]

The .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_EYNcWeCwOBXisdN6i5XqvqvwbPmIQ4/view?usp=sharing

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Could be the *Split Edge* modifier. Have both doors the same edges marked sharp? (marked in cyan color in edit mode) How does it look like when you disable the modifier?

Comment: It looks the same when either edge split or auto smooth is off/on, even if shade smooth is off.

Comment: if you want to have "real" help and not just "guesses" - you should provide blend file

Comment: Okay, I uploaded it but I don't think the materials will be visible since they're using materials from a specific game.

Comment: Reclculcate the normals. in edit mode select all with A then SHIFT N

Comment: I did that several times already, no success.